# How to get the output string from words array and sigBytes from the decoded object in Crypto JS in Javascript or Node JS?

Tags: javascript, encryption, utf-8, base64, cryptojs

I am trying to get json decrypted and base 64 decoded stringified payload coming from API. but after using `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt` I am reciving following as a object.below given is the original payload, key, initVector and encryptedString of `JSON.stringify(payload)`.

```
iv:  1110000348111000
key:  8880002784888000
Original: {"msg":"This is encrypted using AES"}
Encrypted: QxpJspQ5AjeX0HK3uLjSNLZK/i8VWxcXfjpMLghZrSKui/m5XNO5at0jvsI4qGMC
```

Below is the output of `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt` function

```
Decrypted:  {
  words: [
    -1965411475,  1913178924,
      601984393, -1493862515,
     1415172454, -1789306172,
      750380297, -1517138640,
     -934802361,  1164290040,
    -1702889832,  1716466309
  ],
  sigBytes: -85
}
```

Below is my encryption code
`encrypt.js`

```
const encryptPayload = (customerId, payload) => {
  const initializationVector = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(
    initVectorGenerator(customerId)
  );

  const keyForEncryption = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keyGenerator(customerId));
  //   console.log(initializationVector, keyForEncryption);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(payload));
  const encryptedPayload = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
    JSON.stringify(payload),
    keyForEncryption,
    {
      iv: initializationVector,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    }
  );
  const encryptedStr = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(
    encryptedPayload.ciphertext
  );

  console.log(encryptedStr);
};
```

Below is my encryption code
`decrypt.js`

```
const decryptPayload = (customerId, payloadStr) => {
  const initializationVector = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(
    initVectorGenerator(customerId)
  );

  const keyForDecryption = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keyGenerator(customerId));
//   console.log(initializationVector, keyForDecryption);
  //   console.log(payloadStr, "atob(): ", atob(payloadStr));
  const decryptedPayload = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(payloadStr, keyForDecryption, {
    iv: initializationVector,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
  });
  console.log("key: ", decryptedPayload, "iv: ", initializationVector);
  const str = decryptedPayload;

  console.log("str: ", str);

  console.log(atob(str));
  return atob(str.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
};
```

How can I get JSON stringified version of original payload (Original Human Readable string) from this obj of array words and sigBytes ?? Are there any function in crypto js or normal function to convert from words array to original human readable text content ??

Comment: In `encryptPayload()` the return-statement is missing. Apart from this, decryption works on my machine (for the posted test data). However, `return atob(str.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64))` can be simplified with `return str.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)` (but that doesn't actually give an error). Be careful not to reuse any key/IV pairs (just prophylactic, since you didn't post the generator functions).